# What are the supported elements in the RSS 2.0 description tag?

Tags: php, xml, rss, cdata

My problem is I have a php script that produces an RSS feed. It loads the description from an SQL database. The SQL database table is also used to show new posts on my websites homepage. When a user submits a post it can contain a `<li>` tag. Apparently these are not supported in the RSS 2.0 specification. But I can't seem to find a list that shows the tags that are supported.

Here is the feed validation link-

http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http://cryptum.net/post_feed.php

Comment: well an li, not inside a ul\ol is not valid html

Comment: Thanks dagon that didn't cross my mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XML, characters such as `<` and `&` are illegal in elements, so you must escape any elements that will include them. Therefore, you should escape the `<description>` as character data, telling the XML parser to ignore anything in between the `<![CDATA[` and the `]]>`.

```
<description><![CDATA[<p>Your text.</p>]]></description>
```

Comment: No, no no no no no no, you should encode the illegal entities using something like htmlentities(). CDATA is a poor hacky way round. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping

Comment: @James Butler You are incorrect. Using `htmlentities` with turn something like `<` into `&lt;` which includes a `&`. You cannot use `&`s within elements as they are illegal characters. He should escape the data as character data in XML.

Comment: This is exactly what CDATA is designed for, so it is absolutely not, in any way, hacky. It does have the drawback that the data can't include `]]>`, so using entities is a simpler option if you are pragmatically generating content.

Comment: @Michael — Err. `<foo> &lt; </foo>` and `<foo> <![CDATA[<]]> </foo>` are identical. **Neither** is forbidden.

Comment: Maybe hacky was a Slightly wrong word, but it feels a little wrong as you just turning the HTML into a lump of character data, which is it isn't. TBH this is very academic, both will work just as well for your needs.

Comment: Why I hate CDATA segments? I wish I knew. Personal preference, mostly. I just don't like getting used to adding "forbidden characters" inside a special segment where they would suddenly be allowed again. It just confuses me when I see XML mark-up within a CDATA segment and it's not part of the XML surrounding it. At least with encoding I will see that it's encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Using CDATA should be perfectly ok.